# VS code run selection in interactive window doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I have VS code 1.56 where I'm trying to run both python and julia.
I have some problems running selected python code in the interactive windows.
When I press the keybindings (shift + enter) I don't get any action.
I tried to "toggle keyboards shortcuts troubleshooting" and I get the following log

```
[2021-05-11 14:08:54.305] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 13 keybinding entries, matched jupyter.execSelectionInteractive, when: editorTextFocus && jupyter.ownsSelection && !findInputFocussed && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python', source: user extension ms-toolsai.jupyter.
[2021-05-11 14:08:54.308] [renderer1] [error] spawn python ENOENT: Error: spawn python ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

I read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1461655/vs-code-shiftenter-does-not-send-code-to-python-interactive-why) to flag "Jupyter: Send Selection To Interactive Window" but still doesn't work.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like it couldn't spawn the `python` process. Is `python` in the path / accessible from your working directory?

Comment: yes it is, if I write python in the command line i enter in the REPL

Answer (score 11):

I know this thread is old but I have had the same problem for ages. It was not a conflicting keybinding but rather that, for a reason I have not tried to track down, the when condition was not being satisfied.

In my case, I was able to solve the problem by changing the when condition in the Keyboard Shortcuts and removing the "&& jupyter.ownsSelection" block. This restored full functionality.

I previously removed the keybinding for executing code fragment in the terminal, which conflicted.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this.  Was stuck trying to get this exact command (send selected text to interactive) while having *VScodevim* installed, but couldn't get any keyboard shortcut to work. Indeed, removing && jupyter.ownsSelection is the fix.

Answer (score 1):

[image: first image]

In the result list, change the key binding of the shortcuts Run .. in Terminal, Run .. in Interactive Windows and Run Cell to Shift+Enter, Alt+Enter and Ctrl+Enter, respectively, or whatever you like as long as no more conflict shows.

Alternatively, you can also look for all shortcuts with the shift+enter keybiding: Go to

[image: SecondImage]

In the result list, change or delete (right click -> remove keybinding or Delete) the keybinding of the shortcuts that also the same keybinding.